# Disable Screen Capture/ScreenShot in Modal View React Native App

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, screenshot

I have read some approaches to prevent user take screenshot on Android React Native App by adding this code in MainActivity.java

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

However i found it only worked for  component but did not for . I have tried with some 3rd party app like AZ Screen Recorder and it still took a screenshot with the visible modal.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mwwC.png)

How do i disable screen-capturing in modal component ?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?